# Google Apps Script to Move Data from Form Entry to Log w/ UI Input Driven If Statements

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, dialog

I have limited experience with Google's Apps Script but have managed to piece together functional code, until now. Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is to create several Apps Script connected buttons: "New", "Save", "Download" and "Close". The most difficult for me, so far, has been the "Close" button. When the user clicks "Close," the system will first prompt the user to confirm that they wish to "Close" out the data form. After clicking "YES," Apps Script should check for an existing matching CAR Number (CAR numbers are unique) in the CAR Log and, if found, prompt the user with a dialog box to confirm that the data in the matching "CAR Log" row should be overwritten with the data in the "Entry Form". If the user clicks "YES", the data from "Entry Form" is copied and pasted to the row in the "Car Log" with the matching CAR No. If the user clicks "NO", cells containing data on the "Entry Form" will be cleared so that new data can be entered.

Sample Google Sheet w/ Entry Form and CAR Log:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XyOldXz7FoZeAAeToWFbNXJlbHWlgwRkVlo9ifnUZy8/edit?usp=sharing

The intended flow is:

[image: Flow]

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
function FormClose() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var uiConfirmClose = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var responseConfirmClose = uiConfirmClose.alert('Close & Clear all Form Data', 'Are you sure?', uiConfirmClose.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  var destination = ss.getSheetByName('CAR Log');
  var CurrentCARNo = ss.getRange("D5").getValue(); 
  var UsedCARNosRange = SpreadsheetApp.openById("MYSPREADSHEETID").getSheetByName("CAR Log").getRange("A:A");
  var UsedCARNos = UsedCARNosRange.getValues();
  var uiOverwrite = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var responseOverwrite = uiOverwrite.alert('CAR No. '+CurrentCARNo+' Already Exists in Log', 'Would you like to overwrite the log with the data in this form?', uiOverwrite.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  
  // Confirm Close: YES
  if (responseConfirmClose == uiConfirmClose.Button.YES) {
    Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
    
    // Check for Existing CAR No.
    for (var i in UsedCARNos){

      // FOUND
      if (UsedCARNos[i][0].match(CurrentCARNo)!=null){

        // Overwrite?
        if (responseOverwrite == uiOverwrite.Button.YES) {
          Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
          ss.getRange('D5:E5').copyTo(destination.getRange(destination.getLastRow()+1,1,1,1),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,true);
        } 
        else {
          Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.');
        }
      }
    
      // NOT FOUND
      else {
        Logger.log('Data not found. Copy data to log.'); 
        ss.getRange('D5:E5').copyTo(destination.getRange(destination.getLastRow()+1,1,1,1),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,true);
      }
    }
  }
  // Confirm Close: NO
  if (responseConfirmClose == uiConfirmClose.Button.NO) {
    Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.');
    return;
  };
}
```

I will be very grateful for any direction.

Comment: I'm not sure about your logic but do you need a `break;` some where in you loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question clearly, your main goal is to stop your script from running when **No** button gets clicked on your first dialog prompt (`responseConfirmClose`) :

> [image]

### *FINDINGS*

- On your script, `responseOverwrite` runs right away after the first
  dialog `responseConfirmClose` prompt, even after clicking **No**, because it is being **initialized** & **run** at the beginning of your code.

### *SUGGESTION*

- On your logic, I would suggest to place your
  `responseOverwrite` variable inside of your first `if` conditional statement (if
  **YES** button was selected on the `responseConfirmClose` dialog) as seen on the tweaked script below:

### ***[UPDATED]***

### Tweaked Script

```
function runClose() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var uiConfirmClose = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var destination = ss.getSheetByName('CAR Log');
  var carLogData = destination.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var uiOverwrite = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var entryFormData = ss.getSheetByName('Entry Form').getDataRange().getDisplayValues();

  var responseConfirmClose = uiConfirmClose.alert('Close & Clear all Form Data', 'Are you sure?', uiConfirmClose.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  
  if (responseConfirmClose == uiConfirmClose.Button.YES) {
    Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
    for(var i in carLogData){
      var row = parseInt(i) +1;
      if(carLogData[i][0] == entryFormData[4][3]){
        Logger.log("Found a match for \""+"CAR NO. "+entryFormData[4][3]+"\" in row #"+row+ " on the \"CAR Log\" sheet");
        var responseOverwrite = uiOverwrite.alert('CAR No. '+entryFormData[4][3]+' Already Exists in Log', 'Would you like to overwrite the log with the data in this form?', uiOverwrite.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
        // Overwrite?
        if (responseOverwrite == uiOverwrite.Button.YES) {
          Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
          var copyData = [[entryFormData[4][3], //CAR No
                          entryFormData[8][3], //Date Opened
                          entryFormData[8][9], //Originator
                          entryFormData[8][15], //NCP # (if applicable)
                          entryFormData[10][2], //Action Type
                          entryFormData[10][10], //Source
                          entryFormData[12][1], //Issue to
                          entryFormData[12][10], //QMS Reference & Clause
                          entryFormData[17][0], //Description of Nonconformance / Opportunity for Improvement
                          entryFormData[19][0], //Root Cause
                          entryFormData[21][0], //Corrective Action
                          entryFormData[23][5], //Corrective Action Discussed with and Agreed Upon b
                          entryFormData[23][15], //Corrective Action Planned Completion Date
                          entryFormData[28][3], //Approved by
                          entryFormData[28][11], //Date Approve
                          entryFormData[33][3], //Followed up by
                          entryFormData[33][11], //Date of Follow up
                          entryFormData[35][5], //Corrective Action Effective?
                          entryFormData[38][0], //Evidence
                          entryFormData[40][3], //Close Out by
                          entryFormData[40][11]]]; //Date Closed
          destination.getRange("A"+row+":U"+row).setValues(copyData);
        }
        else {
          Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.');
        }
      }
    }

  }else{
    Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.');
  }
  //Code here to empty the fields on "Entry Form" e.q.:
  ss.getRange("D9:E9").clearContent();
  ss.getRange("J9:K9").clearContent();
  ss.getRange("P9:Q9").clearContent();
  ss.getRange("C11:I11").clearContent();
  ss.getRange("K11:O11").clearContent();
  ss.getRange("B13:F13").clearContent();
  ss.getRange("K13:P14").clearContent();
  //continue here for the rest of the fields
}
```

### Sample Demonstration:

- Sample `Entry Form` with data

> [image]

- Sample `CAR Log` with data

> [image]

- After clicking **YES** on the dialog prompt, since there's already a matching `CAR No` on row #4 on the `CAR Log`, it will then be overridden with new data:

> [image]

- `Entry Form` will be cleared after that Or it will be cleared when **No** is clicked from the prompt:

> [image]

Comment: @Ryan Feel free to comment in case there's something else missing Or if I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: You've been extremely helpful. Thank you so much. Could you also help me understand and fix the remaining issues? Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is to create a "CLOSE" button that will allow me to push data (structured as an input form) from a tab in Google Sheet over to another Google Sheets tab where each row is a record. When the user clicks "Close" the system will check for an existing matching record number in the log and, if found, update the data when the user clicks "YES" to the second dialog box.

Comment: You're welcome. Will you be able you update your original post and include a sample sheet for replication & also if possible, a sample flow for `When the user clicks "Close" the system will check for an existing matching record number in the log and, if found, update the data when the user clicks "YES" to the second dialog box` to clearly see how it works?

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, @Irvin. I've updated the flow graphic and pasted a link to a sample sheet. This should make my intentions clearer. Is there anything else I can provide for added clarity?

Comment: Thanks, however, can you try re-sharing your sheet publicly? [See this quick guide - `Change to anyone with link`](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308873?hl=en)

Comment: @Ryan IS Just to clarify, is "`record numbers`" the `CAR No.` on your sheet?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. The CAR No. is the unique key.

Comment: @Ryan I have updated my answer on `Tweaked Script` section, you may copy and paste the codes on your end and test it. Hopefully it will work on your end.

Comment: This is really excellent, Irvin. Thank you very much! In testing, I've noticed that if any of the fields on the "Entry Form" are blank, the data that transferred to the "CAR Log" will be misaligned with the column headers. How could we tweak the code again to keep blanks in tact?

Comment: @Ryan I see, so does this mean that not all fields on `Entry Form` are to be filled in? I intended my script to clean & retrieved all the `Entry Form` data fields that are not empty, meaning all fields should be filled in for it to work properly. I'll try to adjust the script again and use the raw data....

Comment: Sometimes fields will be filled in, other times they will be left blank and then filled in later. I am also adding an "Open" function to allow the user to retrieve data from the CAR Log, edit it in the form, and then save it again to the log (overwriting existing data if the use wishes). If you can help develop this any further, I'd love to see how you do it. If not, I understand and am grateful for all your help. 

Comment: @Ryan I have updated my script and removed the part that cleans the retrieval of the `Entry Form` data fields. It will now retrieve the empty fields. Also, I apologize as we don't really code from scratch for you. Since this post is specifically made for your `Close` function & since you've already included a script code that you've tried, that's why I gave an effort to fix and correct your script/logic on your `Close` function. I'd highly suggest to post a new question &include the code you've tried to reduce multiple concerns in a single StackOverflow question.

Comment: Moreover, you may want also to click the accept/up-vote button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved & they'll easily see this post on their searches.

Comment: Thank you, Irvin. All your help is very much appreciated. Is there some way I can send you a cash tip?

Comment: @Ryan You're very much welcome. I appreciate it & no need for cash tips. Thanks!